# 401 unauthorized issue in "ml-gradle" > v3.4.1

Tags: marklogic, ml-gradle

Seeing a weird issue in ml-gradle.

Just updated the ml-gradle to `v3.16.4` and ML version to `v10.0.2-1`.

On running the below command getting `401 unauthorized` error. On changing the gradle version to `3.4.1` issue is not coming up.

`./gradlew -PmlHost='host' -Penode1='host' -PenvironmentName='some_env' -PmlUsername='admin' -PmlPassword='admin' -b build.gradle mlDeleteAllTasks -i`

**basically whenever there is a communication with management port `8002` getting the error.**

Tried with few different ml-gradle version and observed the below behaviour.

- ml-gradle version is `<= 3.4.1` - `no error`
- ml-gradle version is `> 3.14.1 - 3.17.0` - `401 error is coming`

**Things tried:**

- Tried passing `DIGEST` authentication in the command, but still getting the same error.
- Tried passing the `mlManageUsername/mlManagePassword` params, still no luck.

Comment: Does running with `-i` or `-d` reveal any extra info on which backend call exactly fails?

Comment: no, no extra info.

Comment: Updated the question, please have a look.

Comment: Network issue could very well be. Can you ping 'host' from both machines, or otherwise reach it by that name?

Comment: Try reproducing with curl - a GET request on host:8002/manage/v2 is a reasonable place to start, then try the same DELETE that you're attempting to do. And try that from both machines. I'd check the JVM on each machine too to see if they're different, as you're basically trying to figure out what the difference between the two machines is.

Comment: JVM - I have already gone through this step and make sure both the machines are on same JVM. curl - for this I will give a try.

Comment: with curl I am getting the response. But still failing through ml-gradle while deploying privileges.

Comment: Failing while deploying privileges. `GET request for "http://host:8002/manage/v2/privileges" resulted in 401 (Unauthorized)`